# Calculate Median with condition on Partition By columns

Tags: sql-server-2012

I need to calculate median for Items with label as "Tag" and group with similar Item_Names such as C, E and F. E.g. Median for "Tag C1", "Tag C2" and "Tag C3". For the rest of the items the Median is to be calculated on the basis of Label and Item_Name.

```
Label  ||  Item_Name    ||  Price
Tag    ||  Tag C1       ||   231
Tag    ||  Tag C2       ||   312
Tag    ||  Tag C3       ||   416
Tag    ||  Tag E1       ||   523
Tag    ||  Tag E2       ||   152
Tag    ||  Tag E3       ||   629
Tag    ||  Tag E4       ||   29
Tag    ||  Tag E5       ||   727
Tag    ||  Tag F1       ||   671
Tag    ||  Tag F2       ||   1002
Tag    ||  Tag F3       ||   96
No_Tag ||      G        ||   61
No_Tag ||      H        ||   802
No_Tag ||      H2       ||   36
No_Tag ||      J3       ||   102
No_Tag ||      K        ||   546
No_Tag ||      M        ||   238
```

The below-mentioned query returns Median over the whole set of items

```
PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Label) med_price
```

I tried with CASE as well but it still gives the same result

```
CASE    
    WHEN Item_Name LIKE ('Tag C%') THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Label)
    WHEN Item_Name LIKE ('Tag E%') THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Label)
    WHEN Item_Name LIKE ('Tag F%') THEN PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Label)
    ELSE PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Label, Item_Name)
END AS med_price,
```

How do I include a condition based on "Item_Name" while partitioning over "Label"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the case statement on "Item_Name" - this is a suggestion based on the first five characters of Item_Name being your criteria:

```
    PERCENTILE_CONT(.50) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Price) OVER (PARTITION BY Label, CASE WHEN Label = 'Tag' THEN Left(Item_Name,5) ELSE Item_Name END) AS Med_Price
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Jan.